# Wake Lock android

Tags: android

Не работает WakeLock на андроиде. Имеется приложение - небольшшой сервер на сокетах. Все работает до выключения экрана, после, секунд через 30 сервер становится недоступен. В интернете узнал, что для того чтоб процессор работал даже после выключения экрана надо использовать WakeLock, но у меня почему-то этот способ не работает.
Я делал так

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pow.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "lock");
```

И в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Я изначально запихнул этот код в onCreate активити, и по нажатию на кнопку делал wl.acquire(); но это никак не помогало. Далее я пробовал это перенести в сервис и в класс наследующий Application , но ничего не помогает. Для проверки даже в сервисе сделал дополнительный поток, который через каждый 5 секунд издает звук уведомления, так вот он некоторое время работает и перестает, несмотря на включенную блокировку.

Сделал еще startForeground(777, notification); и заметил еще кое-что. Время от времени когда смартфон находится в спящем режиме сервис оживает, но через некоторое время снова засыпает, мне же надо непрерывную его работу.